# Showing Image From a specific directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this project wherein I need to load pictures from a specific directory.

This code is working:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ShoImages(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/"), "Images/");   
    }
```

Loads perfectly if I'm loading images of "Images" Folder inside my Visual Studio Project, but I want to load images inside a directory I'm getting error using this code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        string strpath = @"D:\New Project\Uploads\12345\";
        ShoImages(Server.MapPath(strpath), strpath);
   }
```

The Error is - "'D:\New Project\Uploads\12345\' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected."

Can you Please help me and give me an idea what to do. New with mappath. Thank you

Comment: Please rename your function to `ShowImages` :)

Comment: Have a look about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MapPath takes a relative URL (`~/Images/`) and changes it into a local path on your machine (`D:\Images`). If you have a local path already, you don't need to call MapPath:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        string strpath = @"D:\New Project\Uploads\12345\";
        ShoImages(strpath, strpath);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found another way. :D I used the HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath instead of just the mappath. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @KimmartinRocero That will return the same issue, surely?

Answer (score 0):

Remove server.map path from ur code

```
  ShoImages(strpath, strpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this :

```
ShoImages(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/12345/"), "Uploads/12345/");
```

instead `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` pointing to my directory.

Thanks for sharing your ideas. Appreciated it. :D